# Creating a URL within a SQL link

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I am trying to create a link in SQL but I am always getting error on the conversion

```
SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max),'<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick=doit("openme","&id="' + id + '"<a>')
FROM mytable
```

If I use `cast` around the id, it works, but do I need to add `cast` to every single value I use?

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that `id` is a number, not a string. When asked to `+` mixed numeric and string operands, SQL Server tries to coerce the string to a number, which is not what you want.

A simple solution uses `concat()`: this function forces string conversion on all its operands.

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(
        ', ',
        '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick=doit("openme","&id="',
        id,
        '"<a>'
    ) newval
FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CONCAT` to implicitly convert the values to a `(n)varchar`:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(', ','<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick=doit("openme","&id="', id,'"<a>')
FROM mytable;
```

There's also no need to use a `MAX` length here, as we can confidently say that your `id` column is not going to have anywhere near 8000 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using SQL Server 2016+ and that `id` is an `int`, you can use `FORMATMESSAGE` as well.

```
SELECT 
    FORMATMESSAGE( ', <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick=doit("openme","&id="%i"<a>', id ) AS link
FROM mytable;
```

Comment: but i am using stuff and this does not seems to be a solution to it

Comment: @Jan You're using `STUFF` as in the function? If so can you update your question with the full example of what you are attempting? Also, please tag your version of SQL Server.